# What do all the items in Drugbound do?

Tags: drugbound

[Drugbound](http://slouchcou.ch/games/drugbound/) is a very neat platformer I just found out about yesterday.  In the game there is a shop where you can buy certain items with "herbs" (This game has a political agenda).

For example, some of the items have interesting names, but doesn't give any clues as to what they do.

The item "Gas Mask of the Facile" for example:

> This device permits the wearer to walk among the common without fear
> of choking on the stupefying miasma they emit. Now that you don't need
> to hold your breath, you are free to go through life at the advanced
> pace you always knew you deserved. Must be equipped.

What do all of the items do?

Comment: @fbueckert I thought we had to tag all flash games as "flash"

Comment: Got a link to that? To my knowledge, platform tags are used to differentiate versions, or if you're asking about the platform itself; if the game itself is only in Flash, then it's sort of redundant to include it.

Comment: @Retrosaur I think that was done so the questions don't end up as Untagged when the single-use tag cleanup runs. Since that no longer happens platform tags should only be needed to specify version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi guys I'm the person making Drugbound, thanks for looking at it. The game is in alpha right now and should be completely done and released on the web on Jan 31st. Until then not all of the items are in the game yet. In fact i'm on my couch finishing up the code for the remaining items as we speak.

That particular item, the Gas Mask of the Facile, currently decreases the time it takes to get to the next levels by 10%. The descriptions are not very explicit, and i think one of the changes i make before launch is to actually make the item descriptions explicit in what the items actually do.

Cheers!
-dave